# Running a .ps1 PowerShell Script From C#

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell, process.start

Attempting to start a .ps1 script by clicking a button in my C# application. My tool will earlier have had you save the file & if PowerShell is selected it will write a text file that looks like this:

```
   PS
   C:\Documents\Test\Test.ps1\
```

The scripts will have already been created & most will accept user input inside the PowerShell script itself. I've tested a few things the following launches a PowerShell window, then flies through the script I am testing with, and finally closes. However if I were to launch the PS script traditionally it would prompt the user for input multiple times, then perform its actions, and finally close.

```
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"powershell.exe", lines[i])
```

However in order for this to work I had to edit the .txt file to the following, and this is useless because it is just spitting out the text of the script itself

```
   PS
   ${C:\Documents\Test\Test.ps1\}
```

Then the following just does not work no matter how I format the .txt file

```
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
                    startInfo.Arguments = lines[i];
                    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    Process process = new Process();
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: the tool is basically used for shortcuts to launch/do various things. So for example I would create a category which would save as a new directory that would then be read and selected from a listbox. Then once selected buttons will then read text files that the user created when creating the category. The buttons can do various things such as changing the clipboard to saved text, launching an .msg file, loading a saved URL, or starting a ps1 script. Essentially anything that may be needed when dealing with the selected category.

Comment: `${C:\Documents\Test\Test.ps1\}` is an example of namespace variable notation, which requests the _contents_ of the file. Apart from that, please update your question to describe the specific problem you're experiencing.